# CTE/with clause in PSQL

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, greenplum

I get ERROR:

> syntax error at or near "INSERT"* on executing the following:

```
WITH
    sq as (select * from input_client)
INSERT INTO cleaned
select *
  from weekly
    cross join sq;
```

Refer(red) the manual for syntax:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html

Comment: Why are you reading the Postgres manual if you are using  [Greenplum](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/580/ref_guide/sql_commands/INSERT.html)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name because Greenplum is based on PostgreSQL 8.3.  CTEs with DML weren't introduced in PostgreSQL until after 8.4 and even in the current codebase on Github, Greenplum doesn't support the DML part of CTEs.

Comment: @JonRoberts Even more reason to read the Greenplum manual and not the Postgres manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO cleaned
select w.*
from weekly w, input_client;
```

If you just want a cartesian product of input_client and weekly, just write it that way.